# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockserver.version.Version

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, mockserver, mockserver-netty

I am trying to start mock server with `mockserver-netty-5.13.2` from shell,
java version:
11.0.9

Rough shell code like this:

```
java -version
echo "start shell before java -jar line"
java -jar ./mockserver-netty-5.13.2.jar -serverPort 9090 -logLevel DEBUG &> ${DIR}/mockserver.log
```

The exception thrown from `java -jar ./mockserver-netty-5.13.2.jar -serverPort 9090`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockserver/version/Version
    at org.mockserver.cli.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockserver.version.Version
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Has anyone run into this issue and resolved it ?
Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the problem within a very similar environment as yours.
The issue is caused because your are using the wrong jar.
To run the `mockserver` from the command line you should use a `-shaded` [jar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297276/what-is-a-shaded-java-dependency), where it's dependencies are included.
The jar you are using does not include the required dependencies and it is not supposed to be ran in the command line without providing them by hand as part of the `classpath`.
The error you get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockserver.version.Version
```

pretty much supports this conclusion, and tells you that the `org.mockserver.version.Version` class is not provided when you run this specific jar.
[Here](https://www.mock-server.com/where/downloads.html), is the official docs that indicate you should use the shaded jar to run mockserver from the command line.
[Here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mock-server/mockserver-netty/5.13.2/mockserver-netty-5.13.2-shaded.jar) you can download the mockserver `5.13.2` shaded jar.
Then, run it like this

```
java -jar ./mockserver-netty-5.13.2-shaded.jar -serverPort 9090 -logLevel DEBUG &> ${DIR}/mockserver.log
```

Hope that helps!